# Trigger windows to build preview images before opening folder

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, thumbnails

Is there any way to trigger Windows 10 to build the various image thumbnail sizes, other than just opening the folder in explorer and waiting?

I have an image export program, and it's exported a large number of files, and I want to scroll through them in the file explorer window. When I open the explorer window, it takes a long time for the previews to generate, and that's only for one size. If I want to see the medium or large icons, it takes even longer.

Is there a way I can tell windows to go ahead and generate thumbnail image previews without opening the folder? As a background task, perhaps, or something I can run while I'm not using the computer?